# Create Vertices of Unit Sphere and Plot as 2D Map in Python

Tags: python, vertices

I'm trying to create vertices of points along the surface of a unit sphere and then unravel the array to create a 2D Map. How would I go about this?

I've thought about doing something like:

```
for i in range(0,360,15):
    for n in range(0,180,15):
        vertices += [[i],[n]]
```

and then create the values in 'vertices' into cartesean coordinates. I just don't know how to create a 2D map from these values. Am I on the right track?
Thank you.

Comment: I think more info is needed. How is this map information stored? Are you trying to project a sphere surface onto a rectangular 2d space?

Comment: I am trying to project cones onto the surface of a sphere then create an image of the sphere in 2D space to show the intersection of the cones as a heat map. The map information is stored as a 2D array where the array is the location of each pixel.

Comment: I asked because I can think of an algorithm but then I realized this is probably not the way to go as it could, in all likelihood, be easily done with some library. Look into Matplotlib, for example.